# Bind a ComboBox ItemsSource to all keys of a ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ResourceDictionary which contains multiple x:Key elements (A list of icons).
I want to bind a ComboBox ItemsSource to the list of keys in the ResourceDictionary.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Name="Icons" Source="..."/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemSource = {Binding ?}> //How to Bind here to Icons keys?
</Grid>
```

I thought about loading the dictionary into the code behind and than using

```
combobox1.ItemsSource = // Load dictionary keys here
```

but I want to know if I can do that xaml directly?

Comment: How are your icons defined, as `Image`, as `ImageSource`, as `Path`, as `DrawingImage`, ...?

Comment: As <PathGeometry x:key="(KeyName)" Figures =.../>

Comment: You can't do it "only in XAML".
Even with the involvement of Sharp, in general terms, it is not clear how this can be implemented. When requesting a resource by key, it is impossible to understand from which resource file this resource will be returned.
There are several solutions: creating a list of keys (in a static class) and getting their values regardless of which resource file they are set in; creating a static class with properties, following the example of Colors and Brushes; getting all values of a valid type (in your case - Geometry) from the resource file (by its Uri).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.
Eventually the solution was pretty simple, the binding should be done like so -

```
<CombBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Icons, Path=Keys}"/>
```